# How to use lines in a file as keyword for grep?

Tags: bash, grep, cat

I've search lots of questions on here and other sites, and people have suggested things that should fix my problem, but I think there's something wrong with my code that I just don't recognize.

I have 24 .fasta files from NGS sequencing that are 150bp long. There's approximately 1M reads for each file. The reads are from targeted sequencing where we electroplated vectors with cDNA for genes of interest, and a unique barcode sequence. I need to look through the sequencing files for the presence or absence of the barcode sequence which corresponds to a specific gene.

I have a .txt list of the barcodeSequences that I want to pass to grep to look for the barcode in the .fasta file. I've tried so many variations of this command. I can give grep each barcode individually but that's so time consuming, I know it's possible to give it the list of barcode sequences and search each .fasta for each of the barcodes and record how many times each barcode is found in each file.

Here's my code where I give it each barcode individually:

```
# Barcode 33
mkdir --mode 755 $dir/BC33
FILES="*.fasta"
for f in $FILES;      do                      
cat "$f" | tr -d "\n" | tr ">" "\n" | grep 'TATTAGAGTTTGAGAATAAGTAGT' > $dir/BC33/"$f"
                      done
```

I tried to adapt it so that I don't have to feed every barcode sequence in individually:

```
dir="/home/lozzib/AG_Barcode_Seq/"
cd $dir
FILES="*.fasta"
for f in $FILES;      do                                              
cat "$f" | tr -d "\n" | tr ">" "\n" | grep -c -f BarcodeScreenSeq.txt | sort > $dir/Results/"$f"
echo "Finished $f"
                      done
```

But it is not searching for the barcode sequences. With this iteration it is just returning new files in the `/Results` directory that are empty. I also tried a nest loop, where I tried to make the barcode sequence a variable that changed like the `$FILES`, but that just gave me a new file with the names of my .fasta files:

```
dir="/home/lozzib/AG_Barcode_Seq/"
cd $dir    
FILES="*.fasta"
for f in $FILES;      do                        
for b in `cat /home/lozzib/AG_Barcode_Seq/BarcodeScreenSeq.txt`; do                   
cat "$f" | grep -c "$b" | sort > $dir/"$f"_Barcode
                      done   ;
                      done
```

I want a output .txt file that has:

```
<barcode sequence>: <# of times that bc was found>
```

for each .fasta file because I want to put all the samples together to make one large excel sheet which shows each barcode and how many times it was found in each sample.

Please help, I've tried everything I can think of.

EDIT

Here is what the BarcodeScreenSeq.txt file would look like. It's just a txt file where each line is a barcode sequence:

```
head BarcodeScreenSeq.txt 
TATTATGAGAAAGTTGAATAGTAG 
ATGAAAGTTAGAGTTTATGATAAG 
AATAGATAAGATTGATTGTGTTTG 
TGTTAAATGTATGTAGTAATTGAG 
ATAGATTTAAGTGAAGAGAGTTAT 
GAATGTTTGTAAATGTATAGATAG 
AAATTGTGAAAGATTGTTTGTGTA 
TGTAAGTGAAATAGTGAGTTATTT 
GAATTGTATAAAGTATTAGATGTG 
AGTGAGATTATGAGTATTGATTTA
```

**EDIT**

```
lozzib@gliaserver:~/AG_Barcode_Seq$ file BarcodeScreenSeq.txt
BarcodeScreenSeq.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: Do you want to count the number of lines the barcode sequence appears in, or the number of times the barcode sequence appears at all (if a barcode appears twice in a single line, does it count as 1 or 2 occurrences)?  Does your `grep` support the `-o` option? Are you allowed to use Perl, or Python, or even Awk?  (Also, what does `150 bp long` mean?  I don't recognize the abbreviation for the units.)

Comment: Also, is there any risk that any of the barcodes you're searching for have overlaps, such that barcode 1 ends with a sequence GTA and barcode 2 starts with sequence GTA, and if you find barcode 1, you might also find barcode 2 overlapping with the end of barcode 1?  I'm not sure that this is a probable problem; would it matter to you if such matches were missed?

Comment: How many lines are there in the `BarcodeScreenSeq.txt` file?  Hundreds, thousands, millions, or more?  The samples are all 24 characters long; are they all the same length?  What is the range of sizes?

Comment: I want to know the number of times the barcode appears. It should only appear once per line, but regardless I just want to know how many times it's found. 

I don't have to use grep, I could use Perl or Python but I don't have any experience writing those types of scripts, so I tried `grep` first. I'm not sure if it supports the `-o` option.  `150 bp long` means the lines are 150 base pairs or characters in length. The files I'm trying to look through were `.fastq` files from an Illumina sequencer and I converted them to `.fasta` files to use `grep` to look for the barcode sequences.

Comment: There are 150 lines in `BarcodeScreenSeq.txt`

Comment: That's helpful; again, please add the information to the question.  As you can probably tell, I don't work in bioinformatics.  150 lines is manageable.  (OTOH, I need to pretend to get some work done; it is going to be a while before I can think about assembling an answer.)

Comment: There have got to be existing bioinformatics tools that can do this .... more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Windows Line Endings

Your `BarcodeScreenSeq.txt` has windows line endings. Each line ends with the special characters `\r\n`. Linux tools such as `grep` only deal with linux line endings `\r` and interpret your file ...

```
TATTATG\r\n
ATGAAAG\r\n
...
```

to look for the patterns `TATTATG\r`, `ATGAAAG\r`, ... (note the `\r` at the end). Because of the `\r` there is no match.

**Either:** Convert your file once bye running `dos2unix BarcodeScreenSeq.txt` or `sed -i 's/\r//g' BarcodeScreenSeq.txt`. This will change your file.
**Or:** replace every `BarcodeScreenSeq.txt` in the following scripts by `<(tr -d '\r' < BarcodeScreenSeq.txt)`. This won't change the file, but creates more overhead as the file is converted over and over again.

## Command

`grep -c` has only one counter. If you pass multiple search patterns at once (for instance using `-f BarcodeScreenSeq.txt`) you still get only one number for all patterns together.

To count the occurrences of each pattern individually you can use the following trick:

```
for file in *.fasta; do
    grep -oFf BarcodeScreenSeq.txt "$file" |
    sort | uniq -c |
    awk '{print $2 ": " $1 }' > "Results/$file"
done
```

`grep -o` will print each match as a single line.
`sort | uniq -c` will count how often each line occurs.
`awk` is only there to change the format from `#matches pattern` to `pattern: #matches`.

**Benefit:** The command should be fairly fast.
**Drawback:** Patterns from `BarcodeScreenSeq.txt` that are not found in `$file` won't be listed at all. Your result will leave out lines of the form `pattern: 0`.

If you really need the lines of the form `pattern: 0` you could use another trick:

```
for file in *.fasta; do
    grep -oFf BarcodeScreenSeq.txt "$file" |
    cat - BarcodeScreenSeq.txt |
    sort | uniq -c |
    awk '{print $2 ": " ($1 - 1) }' > "Results/$file"
done
```

`cat - BarcodeScreenSeq.txt` will insert the content of `BarcodeScreenSeq.txt` at the end of `grep`'s output such that `#matches` is one bigger than it should be. The number is corrected by `awk`.

Comment: If `-o` wasn't supported then `grep` would print an error. Also I have never heard of a `grep` implementation not supporting `-o`. Could it be that your `BarcodeScreenSeq.txt` has windows line endings? Please show us the output of the command `file BarcodeScreenSeq.txt`.

Comment: So the second option gives me a file like you said it would with **BarcodeSequence: # of occurrences** but I get `0` for every single barcode in every single sample. I know that this is incorrect because when I write 1 `grep` command for every barcode like in my original question where `grep` has a sequence listed after it I find barcodes in my `$file` files.

Comment: I added the output as an edit to the original question

Comment: @lozzib Thanks. Didn't see it before. My guess was correct. You have windows line endings and need to convert to linux line endings run `dos2unix BarcodeScreenSeq.txt` to convert the file or replace every `BarcodeScreenSeq.txt` in my script with `<(tr -d '\r' < BarcodeScreenSeq.txt)`

Comment: I’m crying real tears. Thank you so much! It worked! I would have never known about the windows endings causing a problem. Thanks again! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can read a text file one line at a time and process each line separately using a redirect, like so:

```
for f in *.fasta; do 
    while read -r seq; do
        grep -c "${seq}" "${f}" > "${dir}"/"${f}"_Barcode
    done < /home/lozzib/AG_Barcode_Seq/BarcodeScreenSeq.txt
done
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't totally understand. This line:

`while read -r seq; do`

What is seq? And why would the path for the barcode file be at the end?

Comment: `seq` is just the variable name I chose to represent each sequence read from your "BarcodeScreenSeq.txt" file. You can call it anything you like.

The path to the file is at the end because that's how this kind of redirect works: `while read -r [line]; do [whatever with 'line']; done < [file]` reads from the file one line at a time, does whatever the `while` loop says to do with each line, and then loops back to read the next line from the file, etc.